# Tensorflow Object Detection Evaluation Results Question

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0, object-detection, object-detection-api

I am working on an object detector using Tensorflow Object Detection API whereby I downloaded a model from the model zoo repository, specifically ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite_640x640_coco17_tpu-8 to train my custom dataset on which contains 2500 images split into 70:30 training and testing ratio. I have edited the pipeline.config file accordingly following a tutorial, where I added the label_maps paths and other requirements. I have trained this model for 50,000 steps and monitored the training process on tensorboard which displayed good training progress results. Now the issue occurred when I went to evaluate the model. For some reason, the evaluation results are the following:

[image]

What could possibly be the issue, since the loss graphs seem to be good and even the learning rate graphs? Thanks

Comment: What is the format of your ground-truth? Can you paste one of the bounding box coordinates that you used here?

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi the image bounding boxes were created with labelImg in XML format, then they were passed through a python script which generated the training and testing records.

Comment: Did you check this [post](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/6021#issuecomment-520014123). As another santiy check, you can use [this](https://github.com/sulc/tfrecord-viewer) to test  your annotations for a few images before proceeding to train

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi thanks for these sources. I will check on them.

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi I have used the provided [source](https://github.com/sulc/tfrecord-viewer) and all images are loading correctly with their classes and set annotation, so in my opinion, the TFrecord files are not the problem.

Comment: Just to clarify, you checked this for both train and val/test `record` files right?

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi Yes, both of them are correct

Comment: I guess you used [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/training.html#evaluating-the-model-optional) command for evaluation? Not sure if it's going to make a difference, but maybe you can try validation using `eval.py` and see if it makes a difference? It should be located in the `object_detection/legacy` folder and its usage is mentioned [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/41f71f6c9798c170fcbfeae220092d7c2824d813/research/object_detection/legacy/eval.py#L24)

Comment: @JiteshMalipeddi Yes, exactly I followed that tutorial. I will try using the eval.py instead since I used the model_main_tf2 for both training and evaluation